# Reducing the method calls by creating global variables

Tags: java, global-variables

IN my Code i have 4 methods and all the methods are calling single method. To avoid duplicate method calls i have created a global variable and have stored the method result in that. I was told that it is not a good idea. Do we have any other alternative for this ?

```
 public void initializePortletData(PortletRequest request, PortletResponse portletResponse, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(TABLE, test(request));
    }

    public void getInvitedUsers(PortletRequest request, PortletResponse response, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(TABLE, test(request));
    }

    @Override
    public Map getJSParams(PortletRequest request, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();

            model.put(TABLE, test(request));

        return model;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the case maybe you could have the method set some class variable before returning. The next time the method is called return this value rather then calculating it again.

Comment: I did that but i was told that it will cause concurrency issues

Comment: Saving any information in a variable could potentially cause concurrency issues if the variable is accessed from many threads and the concurrency is not handled. You could leave the code as is, or solve the concurrency problem somehow. Have a look at the synchonize method in Java.